# Register with HTML form and PHP script

Tags: php, html-email

```html
<form action="email.php" method="post">
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required="name">
</div>
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
</div>
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
<input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required="">
</div>
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" required="">
</div>
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="text" name="talent" placeholder="Talent" required="">
</div>
<div class="icon1">
<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="text" name="university" placeholder="Universities" required="">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</div>
</form>
```

I am having problem when submitting the form i am only getting the following on my email, please assist.

when receiving the email i am only receiving the labels not the actual data that was completed on the form.

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];
$Age = $_POST['age'];
$Talent = $_POST['talent'];
$University = $_POST['university'];

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "Registration";
$message = "Name: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Phone: $phone \n\n Age: $age 
\n\n Talent: $talent \n\n University: $university";
$from = "info@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see html of your form.  You should also specify more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated my code see my html form

Comment: Any good PHP editor or even the PHP server itself should tell you at least what your main problem is here (you should run the script with [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) PHP settings or in debug mode). then you get an error like this: `Notice: Undefined variable: name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is case sensitive you use uppercase variables ($Name) but you use smallcase ($name)
try it :

firstly you should use :

```
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name"  required="name">
```

secondly :

```
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Phone = $_POST['phone'];
$Age = $_POST['age'];
$Talent = $_POST['talent'];
$University = $_POST['university'];

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "Registration";
$message = "Name: $Name \n\n Email: $Email\n\n Phone: $Phone \n\n Age: $Age
\n\n Talent: $Talent\n\n University: $University";
$from = "info@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: i have update my post see the form.

Comment: I have changed as mentioned above and now I am not even receiving the email.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here. You didn't actually use the `name="name"` attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required="name">
```

Change that to:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required="name">
```

I always make it a habit of using both `id` and `name` in my form inputs. Only the `name` attribute is passed on to the form action.

Also, as the other user pointed out, you have to have consistent variable names. `$Name` is different than `$name`, etc.

Comment: #Difster & #andreas karimi Thanks, it is now working. thanks again :-)